# Generate Rest api in java from .json file with swagger

Tags: java, rest, swagger

Does it exist any code generator that from .json will convert the file into an Api rest in Java ?
I'm aware that exist some framwork to generate the .json, such as io.swagger, io.springfox, com.mangofactory etc., but i wasn't able to find anything about the opposite process.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/, not sure if it works for your use case but worked for me for similar use case

Answer (score 0):

Please try [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) (free, open-source), which supports both [OpenAPI spec v2, v3](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification).

To use it, simply download the JAR or use Docker images, maven plug-in or gradle plug-in. The [Getting Started](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#2---getting-started) section is a good starting point.

If you've Docker installed, please try:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml \
    -g java \
    -o /local/out/java
```